# Incompatible type of pointer

Tags: c, pointers

When I try to compile and run my program there is a warning in the error box

> [Warning] assignment from incompatible pointer type

for this code:

```
char *A_ptr;

char names[numOfNames][20];

A_ptr = names;
```

I can't understand why it doesn't accept it.

Comment: The correct declaration is `char (*A_ptr)[20]`. Your declaration of `A_ptr` would work with `char names[20]`, but it's not compatible with an array of character arrays.

Comment: It would be useful to see what you're doing with `A_ptr` after its assignment.

Comment: Oops! My bad...

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a pointer to char array of size 20. The correct declaration is:

```
char (*A_ptr)[20];
```

Don't mix it up with this:

```
char *A_ptr[20];
```

because that is an array of 20 pointers to char, which is something completely different.

Good site for these kind of stuff: https://cdecl.org/